# Deserialize Json an access the result

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have this Json:

```
{
   "UpdatePack":"updatePacks\/1585654836.pack",
   "Updates":[
      {
         "Name":"MsgBoxEx",
         "version":"1.5.14.88",
         "ChangeLog":"BugFix: Form didn't resize correct.",
         "Hash":"5FB23ED83693A6D3147A0485CD13288315F77D3D37AAC0697E70B8F8C9AA0BB8"

},
      {
         "Name":"Utilities",
         "version":"2.5.1.58",
         "ChangeLog":"StringManagement updated.",
         "Hash":"05E6B3F521225C604662916F50A701E9783E13776DE4FCA27BE4B69705491AC5"

}

]
}
```

I have created 2 classes to be used to Deserialize it.

```
class UpdatesList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string ChangeLog { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
class JsonObjectHolder
{
    public string UpdatePack { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<int, MyData> { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, UpdatesList> Updates { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to access the dictionary, I keep getting `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at " Console.WriteLine(jsonTest.Dict.Count);"`

Am I Deserializing it wrong, or do I need to do some thing else to access the result of the dictionary?

I'm new to both C# and Json.

I hope that some one could point me in the right direction on how to handle this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 latest update, and .net 4.8.
Regards
/LR

Comment: It isn't a collection, it just two properties with 0 and 1 names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code doesn't work because `0` and `1` tokens just a properties, not the array items (you don't have square brackets `[]` around them). You can parse these values to desired structure manually using [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(your_json_string);
var dict = new Dictionary<int, UpdatesList>();
foreach (var item in json.Properties())
{
    if (item.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        var index = int.Parse(item.Name);
        var updateList = item.Value.ToObject<UpdatesList>();
        dict.Add(index, updateList);
    }
}

var holder = new JsonObjectHolder
{
    UpdatePack = json["Updates"]?.Value<string>(),
    Dict = dict
};
```

**Update:** According to OP changes made to JSON it might be deserialized even more simply

```cs
var list = json["Updates"]?.ToObject<List<UpdatesList>>();

var holder = new JsonObjectHolder
{
    UpdatePack = json["UpdatePack"]?.Value<string>(),
    Dict = list.Select((updatesList, index) => new { updatesList, index })
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.updatesList)
};
```

The main point here is that `Updates` is an array of items, not the key-value collection. It can be transformed into `Dictionary<int, UpdatesList>` using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8) method from `System.Linq` (or just use `List<UpdatesList>` as is)

Comment: Hi Sry. I pasted the wrong json, it was a hardcoded test code, I have updated the Question with the correct json.

Comment: @Lupus then you can deserialize the updated json only to list, there is no indices. Or add them manually. Do you need a `Dictionary<int, UpdatesList>()`?

Answer (score 2):

The exception you're getting essentially means the value is being accessed before the object is initialized.

A better, simpler and cleaner way to doing it is using NewtonSoft. (you can easily get it as a Nuget package)

example:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and then usage:

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Source: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Hi, I do use Json.Net (I should had added that to my question, my bad), I already read the json help, but sadly I'm not wise enough to understand how to do it according to the help file.

Comment: Alright. Please elaborate where exactly are you facing the problem? because above sample could should be sufficient enough to implement. Do you face problems installing Newtonsoft? If yes, you can install it using the Nuget package manager from Visual studio. A small google query should give you a tutorial to install Nuget packages. If there's any other problem that you're facing, please do let me know. I'll try to do whatever I can to help.

Comment: I couldn't access the directory. When I tried to get a count I got the NullExcption.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need `Dictionary<int, UpdatesList> Updates`, when you can easily just use `List<Update> Updates`, since your updates are in a JSON array.

I would model your classes like this:

```
public class Update
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string ChangeLog { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string UpdatePack { get; set; }
    public List<Update> Updates { get; set; }
}
```

You can then deserialize with:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Try it out on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AM14W6)

**Note:** To convert JSON to C# classes, you can go to **Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes** inside Visual Studio. Make sure you have copied the JSON to your clipboard before using it. You will get classes similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

your data and the class is not compatible. if you change the string like this it would work.

change "Updates" to "UpdatePack" and add "Dict" around the dictionary items.

```
{
   "UpdatePack":"updates\/4D1D7964D5B88E5867324F575B77D2FA.zip",
   "Dict":{
      "0":{
         "Name":"MsgBoxEx",
         "Version":"1.0.123.58",
         "ChangeLog":"Bugfix:Form didn't resize correct",
         "hash":"AA94556C0D2C8C73DD217974D252AF3311A5BF52819B06D179D17672F21049A6"
      },
      "1":{
         "Name":"Utilities",
         "Version":"1.5.321.87",
         "ChangeLog":"StringManagement updated",
         "hash":"2F561B02A49376E3679ACD5975E3790ABDFF09ECBADFA1E1858C7BA26E3FFCEF"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi You are right, it was a test code I pasted and not the right one.